# How to make entry like editor in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin-entry

I am creating a mobile application in that I need to send a message for query or support when the user creates that type of message and then click on return or done from keyboard entry height should be adjusted and if the user clicks on the back than it should also be managed. In that, I am not able to use `Editor` control.
I am using a shared project to develop the application.

I try with the following code:

**Sample.xaml**

```
 <StackLayout Padding="50" HeightRequest="150">
    <Entry TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" x:Name="EntryCustom"/>
 </StackLayout>
```

**Sample.xaml.cs**

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    int isElse = 0;
    if (args != null && args.OldTextValue != null && args.NewTextValue != null)
    {
        string[] oldval = args.OldTextValue.Split('\r');
        string[] Newval = args.NewTextValue.Split('\r');
        if (oldval.Count() > Newval.Count())
        {
            EntryCustom.HeightRequest = EntryCustom.HeightRequest - 33;
            isElse = 2;
        }
        else
            isElse = 1;
    }
    if (args.OldTextValue != null && (args.NewTextValue == "\n" || args.NewTextValue.EndsWith("\r")) && EntryCustom.HeightRequest < 100 && (isElse == 1 || args != null || args.OldTextValue.Count() > args.NewTextValue.Count()))
        EntryCustom.HeightRequest = EntryCustom.HeightRequest + 33;
}
```

Can anyone look into this and suggest me what should I have to change in the code?

Comment: I'm not understand your question clearly, why can't you use a Editor with  AutoSize="TextChanges? And what's your requirement?

Comment: In a chat application if I am using Editor than in iOS it display Done above right corner of the keyboard and that is like weird for the chat application so I don't want to use that. If anything that manage by rendere than it's also fine for me to work.

Comment: You want to change the Done on the keyboard? Can you add a  screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Editor. Use `<Editor AutoSize="TextChanges"/>` and the editor will adjust it's size based on the entered text.